# Are there any best practices on how to extract parameters from class constructor in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a class:

```
class CleanerService: CleanerServiceProtocol {

    private let databaseService: DatabaseServiceProtocol
    private let localStorageService: LocalStorageServiceProtocol
    private let preferenceService: PreferenceServiceProtocol
    private let tooltipService: TooltipServiceProtocol

    init(databaseService: DatabaseServiceProtocol, storageService: LocalStorageServiceProtocol, preferenceService: PreferenceServiceProtocol, tooltipService: TooltipServiceProtocol) {
        self.databaseService = databaseService
        self.localStorageService = storageService
        self.preferenceService = preferenceService
        self.tooltipService = tooltipService
    }

}
```

And I want to minimize actual parameters number. But I also want to make sure my injected variables are not accessible outside the class (like private get).

From common practices, are there any good looking solutions?
Maybe worth extracting it using structure with parameters or just use class setters?

Comment: You can use property wrapper.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini haven't found nothing about how property wrappers could help here. Could you please elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: All you want to do is reduce the size of the initializer?

Comment: @bsod yeah, right

Comment: These properties have to be initialized somewhere so all you would do is do it somewhere else and make your code harder to read. What’s the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using a tuple (multiple?) as a typealias.

```
typealias Dependencies = {
    databaseService: DatabaseServiceProtocol
    // ...
}

class CleanerService: CleanerServiceProtocol {
    private let dependencies: Dependencies

    init(dependencies: Dependencies) {
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }
}
```

But this has downsides:

- adding or removing dependencies becomes hard, you don't really know
  what was added or removed as Xcode is not smart enough
- you always
  need to type `dependencies.something` to access a dependency.

So I've reverted back into using parameters.
Maybe this would work for you.